# How can I train my data set in Matlab using Caffe?

Tags: matcaffe

If I already have `deploy.prototxt`,`solver.prototxt`,`train_val.prototxt`.How can I code in matlab to call function of Caffe to train my data set.I know  `caffe-master\matlab\demo` there is a demo code but it just for classsification not train.Who have a complete code about how to train one's own data set?